# Issue with floats

Tags: c++, floating-point, accelerometer, microcontroller

hopefully this turns out to be a simple questions, I'm just having a brain fart.  I've never used floats before so I think I'm just doing something wrong.

The Project: I'm reading in accelerometer values and [roughly] estimating distance traveled.  I know it's not too accurate but I only need to measure a couple feet of something that's on rails, so I only need one axis.

Accelerometer is set up to record at 100Hz, sending an interrupt every 10 samples, so I read 10 samples every 100ms, and average them.  This is no problem, spits me out rock solid readings.  Where I lose it is calculating the distance traveled (inches.)  Any help would be much appriciated it.  Here's the snippets of code in question...

Variables:

```
int AccelX;
int PrevAccelX;
char HeightChar;

float Height;
float PrevHeight;
float Velocity;
float PrevVelocity;
```

Defines:

```
#define ACCEL_CONVERT       1.50574 //386.088in/s^2 / 256.41 LSB
#define ACCEL_SAMPLE_TIME   0.1   //10 samples @ 100Hz
```

Accelerometer has 256.41 "counts" per G, or each LSB is 3.9mg.

Calculating distance (height):

```
//Convert to Acceleration
AccelX *= ACCEL_CONVERT;    //convert to in/s^2

//First Integration
Velocity = PrevVelocity + (PrevAccelX + 
        ((AccelX - PrevAccelX)/2.0))*ACCEL_SAMPLE_TIME;

//second integration
Height = PrevHeight + (PrevVelocity +
       ((Velocity - PrevVelocity)/2.0))*ACCEL_SAMPLE_TIME;

//save current values as previous, for next measurement
PrevVelocity = Velocity;
PrevHeight = Height;
PrevAccelX = AccelX;
```

Here I try to round the float to an int and display it.  I can't simply print the float, not enough space left on the uC to do that.

```
HeightChar = (Height + 0.5f);
printf ("Height: %d in    \r", HeightChar);
```

This spits out a number that looks like it climbs and falls orders of magnitude faster than expected.  I'm thinking that it may just be the float with the decimal taken out?

I also need to compare the height, not sure if it's kosher to compare a float or not.

```
if (Height > X){
    //do something
}
```

or

```
if (HeightChar > X){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I am having a hard time getting a concrete question out of your post, what exactly is your question? Yes you can compare to floats all you want, it works exactly as you'd expect ([most of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1)) be careful with equality comparisons using floats and doubles.

Comment: Just a tip: Keep it in the natural units until output. Write down your formula on paper, and try to suss it out.

Comment: Why is `AccelX` an `int`?!

Comment: Any reason in particular why you are converting your float to a `char` (bearing in mind that the overflow in the conversion from float to an integer type is undefined behavior)?

Comment: @Cyber - The question is basically just can you see where my data is getting bugned up?

Comment: @Deduplicator - I'll try that, been at it all weekend though so I think the equations are solid.

Comment: @KerrekSB - I see what you're getting at.  It was always a whole number but won't be after the multiplication.  I doubt that has that much effect on error but I'll patch it up.

Comment: @PascalCuoq - because I don't have enough program space to use printf with a float.  I'm only doing this to print a value for debugging.

Comment: @user3720724 And you aren't afraid that the computed value will be larger than 128? If you are printing this value for debugging, wouldn't it make sense to avoid being sent on the wrong track by an overflow in the computation of the very value that is supposed to help you debug?

Comment: @KerrekSB - Tried that, I created a float AccelXF, set AccelXF = AccelX then used AccelXF and it didn't make much difference.

Comment: You're wasting code space to convert AccelX back and forth between int and floats in the first 3 assignments. You can use all floats to remove the converting functions. But IMHO the range of the acceleration values are so limited that fixed-point may be much more helpful in this case. Also, printing hex maybe even faster than convert to char and print.

Comment: Velocity and Height can be easily done in integer or fixed-point maths like `Velocity = PrevVelocity + (PrevAccelX + ((AccelX - PrevAccelX)/2))/10;`. If you need correct rounding then adjust it a little bit